# How to make the navigation inside the page smother?

Tags: html, web, navigation

I'm using the navigation with the anchor, like: `<a href="#teste">`
`<div id="teste"></div>`; But when I click on the link, it's too fast, I wanna to this be more smoth. There's a way to do this only in html, or whitout Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want it to smoothly scroll to that div? Heres a code snippet to help. Use the css `scroll-behavior` property with `smooth` as its value.

```css
* {scroll-behavior: smooth;}
```

```html
<a href="#teste">Go to #teste </a>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="teste"> #teste</div>
```

Comment: Thanks bro, I thought i would have to use javascript, that would break all logic on the page. you are a lifesaver.